# Degrees of freedom in simple linear regression (when bo is known)

Tags: regression, degrees-of-freedom

I am wondering if you would be able to help me with some linear regression model problems. It is about a simple linear regression model and I am very confused with the degrees of freedom. Here is a problem,

Considering the simple linear regression model
Y=bo+b1*xi+ei
where the intercept bo is known and ei~N(o,sigma^2) (iid).

In this case, how can I determine the degrees of freedom?
I thought the degrees of freedom of SST should be n and SSE should be n-1 because b0 is known (constant). Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, you are right.